# How do I effectively use supply lines?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

So I was wondering what I could do about my supply problem.

It goes as followed: In the year 1939 I invade the Soviet Union as Germany. I use the advantage of them having the great purge. There was one tiny little problem though, my supply lines are getting way to stretched and I can't build new supply lines that fast. Any good ideas to still be able to keep my troops supplied?